# how To pass onclick Icon In javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

In My old  code have select options value  have in  Monthly MIp

```
<td>Monthly MIP </td>
<td>
   <input name="monthlymippc" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:monthlyMIPPcChanged(true)" />
%</td>
<td>Or $
    <input name="monthlymipamt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:monthlyMIPAmountChanged(true)"/>
</td>
<td>
   <select name="monthlymipfrequency">
      <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
      <option value="quarterly">Quarterly</option>
      <option value="semianually">Semi Anually</option>
      <option value="anually" selected>Anually</option>
    </select>
```

this is working . Now changed new UI options value used `onclick` icon function

[image]

My New UI code monthly MIP used onclick . The A, Q, S, M ICON works exactly like the annual, semi-annual, quarterly, monthly working Drop down box old UI.

Now My UI used ICON.The only difference is that there was not enough room for a ddb on the UI so we made it an ICON. how to  pass my old Ui code in onclick ICON CHANGE .
MY new UI code :

```
  var id;
  var eve;
  var ImageName;
  function changeperiod(event, _id, _src) {
      id = _id;
      eve = event;
      //alert(_id);
      var img = _src.substring(_src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      ImageName = img;
      $('#mymodal').modal()
        if (ImageName == "A.png") {
            //alert(ImageName);
            $("#annual").prop('checked', true);
            $("#semi").prop('checked', false);
            $("#querter").prop('checked', false);
            $("#month").prop('checked', false);
        }
        if (ImageName == "Q.png") {
            //alert(ImageName);
            $("#querter").prop('checked', true);
            $("#annual").prop('checked', false);
            $("#semi").prop('checked', false);
            $("#month").prop('checked', false);

        }
        if (ImageName == "S.png") {
            // alert(ImageName);
            $("#semi").prop('checked', true);
            $("#querter").prop('checked', false);
            $("#annual").prop('checked', false);
            $("#month").prop('checked', false);

        }
        if (ImageName == "M.png") {
            //alert(ImageName);
            $("#month").prop('checked', true);
            $("#semi").prop('checked', false);
            $("#querter").prop('checked', false);
            $("#annual").prop('checked', false);

        }
        // $('#save').hide();
        $('#trigger').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#trigger').addClass('disabledButton');
      }
    var value;
    $('#myForm input').on('change', function () {
        value = $('input[name="a"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
        $('#trigger').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#trigger').removeClass('disabledButton');
    });
    $('#trigger').on('click', function () {
        if (value == "A") {
            $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/A.png");
        }
        if (value == "S") {
            $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/S.png");
        }
        if (value == "Q") {
            $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/Q.png");
        }
        if (value == "M") {
            $(eve.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/M.png");
        }
        $('#mymodal').modal('hide');
    });



<div class="pop-body" style="text-align:left">
   <form id="myForm"style="padding-left: 50px;">
       <p><input id="annual" name="a" type="radio" class="period" value="A"/> &nbsp Annual</p>
       <p><input id="semi" name="a" type="radio" class="period" value="S" /> &nbsp Semi-Annual</p>
       <p><input id="querter" name="a" type="radio" class="period" value="Q" /> &nbsp Querterly</p>
       <p><input id="month" name="a" type="radio" class="period" value="M" /> &nbsp Monthly</p>

   </form>
</div>
```

Please help me anyone?